# (Aqua) Emacs on MacOS X becomes unresponsive when visiting particular text file, or pasting

Tags: macos, emacs, freeze

My emacs on MacOS X (Aquamacs? Based on Emacs 22.3.1) stops responding when I paste a particular text from a log file, or reads (visit-file) a file that contains the text. It shows loading of cl-mode module, and then it starts making whistling sounds. It does not respond to any key strokes or menu selections. I have to kill the process and remove ~/Library/Saved Application State/org.gnu.Emacs.savedState folder in order to restore the health. (If I don't remove the file, it tries to load the same file with offending content and dies.)

I am guessing that a particular pattern of the text content triggers loading of cl-mode module, and because the content of the text isn't really a Common Lisp program, it goes into a strange mode. Is there a way to disable this auto-sensing of the mode by the text content?

Comment: You can disable automatic mode selection by opening the file with `M-x find-file-literally`.

Comment: @legoscia, thank you. I could open the offending file and it even shows me what byte sequences are causing this!

Comment: Great to hear! If that solved your problem, you can [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so anyone having the same problem can find the solution.